# VSCode Debugging Mocha - Breakpoints Not Working?

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, mocha.js

I'm trying to debug my mocha tests with VSCode. The tests run to completion, but for some reason any breakpoints I set in my test file are greyed out and ignored with message, "Unverified breakpoints, breakpoints set but not yet bound." Here's my launch.json config:

```
{
  "name": "Run mocha",
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
  "stopOnEntry": false,
  "args": [
    "--recursive",
    "--compilers",
    "js:babel-core/register",
    "--require",
    "babel-polyfill",
    "--no-timeouts",
    "--colors"
  ],
  "runtimeExecutable": null,
  "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
  "env": { "NODE_ENV": "testing" },
  "sourceMaps": false
}
```

I've gone through different Github issue threads and SO questions but have yet to get it to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you get this to work?